# Invalid Subquery yet outer query returns the records

Tags: sql, oracle11g, subquery

I've two table EMP & DEPT. Below are the descriptions.

```
**EMP table:**

EMP_ID        NUMBER      
EMP_NAME      VARCHAR2(4)

**DEPT table:**

DEPT_ID        NUMBER      
DEPT_NAME      VARCHAR2(4)
```

when i run the below query it executed successfully even though the subquery is invalid.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMP_ID IN (SELECT SAL FROM DEPT);
```

I am expecting **ORA-00904 : invalid identifier**, but it returns the records from EMP table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Oracle supports correlated subqueries one level deep. So the scope of the columns in the outer query includes the subquery in your example.

The query you wrote is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   EMP
WHERE  EMP_ID IN (SELECT EMP.SAL
                  FROM   DEPT);
```

It also highlights the need to adequately alias your queries - if you had written:

```
SELECT *
FROM   EMP
WHERE  EMP_ID IN (SELECT DEPT.SAL
                  FROM   DEPT);
```

then you would have gotten the error you were expecting.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I tried by using alias and got an error.

Answer (score 0):

This happen when the result of the subquery is not null.

In your case it seems that, strangely, instead report the error that the column does not exist, the result is returned in order to be non-null and then select the top is still done